# Cannot connect to Google Datalab notebook

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I am using windows 10 and Chrome.  After creating a Datalab VM, I clicked on Preview at port 8081.  In the new browser instance, I clicked on add a new notebook.  It opens the notebook, but gives the following error

A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration.

Since the connection has failed, nothing works.  How to get the connection?  How to check the notebook server configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue.  Brand new "datalab create "  Once the gui opens you hit new notebook and get the message:

> A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration.

You close the failed open and the directory listing shows the untitled notebook and the icon shows it as running.  Try to open it again.  Same error.

Answer (score 0):

You have no connection anymore. Go back to your shell and write the following command `datalab connect your_VM`.
It will say

```
Connecting to your_VM.
This will create an SSH tunnel and may prompt you to create an rsa key pair.
Waiting for your_VM to be reachable at http://localhost:8081/
Enter passphrase for key '/some_path/.ssh/google_compute_engine':
```

Enter your passphrase and wait until you see this:

```
The connection to your_VM is now open and will remain until this command is killed.
Click on the *Web Preview* (up-arrow button at top-left), select *port 8081*, and start using your_VM.
```

Then go to the `*8081*` port as indicated.

If this doesn't work, kill the shell with `Ctrl + c` and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

While having the same issue, I changed browser I'm using to connect with Datalab. It's the temporary workaround, but at least I know that te issue is on the browser side.

Clearing Chrome's cache and browsing data won't help though.